# Duda con expresiones regulares

Tags: regex

Tengo una duda sobre un ejercicio de regex que tengo que hacer y lo tengo casi, pero me falta la última parte que es la de que no pueda haber dos puntos seguidos. No logro dar con la tecla...

Por si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias

https://ibb.co/JHqfsqw

Edito:

este es el código

```java
public static boolean validarEmail (String email){

    String regex = "[^\\.]([A-Za-z0-9-_\\.]{1,64})@[^\\.]([A-Za-z\\.0-9]{4,255})[\\.][A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher comparador = patron.matcher(email);
    return comparador.matches();
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor carga el código como texto, no podemos ayudarte sin él. Por cierto, puedes insertar fácilmente las imágenes, no es necesario que utilices otra página en la que cargarlas.